# How to include php page which include also a css file?

Tags: php, html, css, footer

I have searched a lot over stackoverflow and found related answer but those were not perfect solution of this problem. 
I have a directory named root. Inside the root folder there are 1 folder named footer and 1 file named index.php
There are 2 files named footer.php and footer.css in the footer directory. I want to include footer.php file from
index.php page. footer.php page has a stylesheet link with footer.css page. But index.php page can not find footer.css
page.

Please see code from Pastebin.

[footer.php](http://pastebin.com/GM8LSkCU)

[index.php](http://pastebin.com/u6n4CFrz)

Comment: please paste code here

Comment: @Dagon There isn't enough room if they paste it next to your comment :p

Comment: @Fred-ii- not *here* here, but *there* here, you silly bear.

Comment: @Dagon Oh, "that" there "here". Silly *quack* that I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce horrible html code ...
footer.php is a full html page - it has Doctype, html tag, body tag etc.
The same goes with index.php.
Including footer.php in index.php will produce invalid html file, with html tag inside another html tag (html > body > html > body) ...

The reason why You can't see footer.css it's because it's placed in footer directory. So while you request index.php the proper path to css should be footer/footer.css, and You're getting just footer.css (because path for footer.php is relative).

Answer (score 1):

When you "include" the footer.php, you are adding that code to your index.php. So since the css is being called from the index.php, it should reference "footer/footer.css".